# How can I speed up interaction/drawing with a TreeListView

Tags: c#, performance, objectlistview, treelistview

I am trying to use the TreeListView from this open source package (http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).  The code I've worked out builds the TreeListView fine but it is slow to draw the items and slow upon click.

My data model consist of parent Documents and child DocumentVersions (I'm using a Composite Design Pattern which is the reason for the ProjectComponent class below.  Each Document can have any number of DocumentVersions; a DocumentVersion cannot have any children.  Here are my classes (I've stripped out irrelevant most code for brevity):

```
abstract public class ProjectComponent
{
    public abstract bool HasChildren { get; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Document : ProjectComponent
{
    public virtual List<DocumentVersion> DocumentVersions { get; set; }
    public override bool HasChildren
    {
        get { if (this.DocumentVersions.Count > 0) return true; else return false;}
    }
}

public class DocumentVersion : ProjectComponent
{
    public int VersionNo { get; set; }
    public DocumentType Type { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Document")]
    public int DocumentID { get; set; }
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public override bool HasChildren
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

To build the TreeListView, I pull all of my Documents in a list (CurrentDocumentList) and then build the tree as follows:

```
    void InitializeTV2(TreeListView tlv)
    {
        tlv.HideSelection = false;
        tlv.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x)
        {
            return ((ProjectComponent)x).HasChildren;
        };
        tlv.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x) { return ((Document)x).DocumentVersions; };
        tlv.Roots = CurrentDocumentList;
    }
```

The result is an accurate TreeListView but it is not very responsive (slow to draw when expanding and slow upon any click).  CanExpandGetter is hit frequently but this is normal behavior according to the documentation.

If anyone has any hints on how I can make this faster, I'd appreciate it.  (The sample project using the FileSystemInfo that came with the package works very fast on my machine so its clearly my code).

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, looks fine to me as well. Also, the OLV caches the child objects. Is it the same behavior when you expand the node the second time?

Comment: That looks fine to me. You might want to run a profiler over the code and see where it is actually spending its time. ANTS profiler and JetBrains dotTrace both have eval versions you could use.